# Span a table with different tabular features over several pages

Tags: tables, longtable, tabu

I have a table environment with different tabular environments and I am wondering how to enforce a page break. `longtable` does not work as the number of columns is different for the different tabulars, `\pagebreak` is also of no help.

So, how can I create tables with several panels which span over several pages?

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{An interesting table}
    \subcaption*{Panel A: Some stuff}
    \begin{tabular}{lcr}
        First name & Last name  & Product \\
        Bubba & Gump & Shrimp \\
        Steve & Jobs & Happiness
    \end{tabular}
   \pagebreak
    \bigskip
    \subcaption*{Panel B: Other stuff}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        School & State \\
        Harvard & MA \\
        Yale & CT \\
        Brown & RI
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

**Edit (based on comment of @koleygr)**
The page break works using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\centering
\captionof{table}{My caption}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
First name & Last name  & Product \\
Bubba & Gump & Shrimp \\
Steve & Jobs & Happiness
\end{tabular}
\bigskip
\pagebreak
\captionof{table}{My caption}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
School & State \\
Harvard & MA \\
Yale & CT \\
Brown & RI
\end{tabular}
```

\end{document}

However, this creates inconsistent caption numberings.

Comment: the only problem is that you use table environment that is a float for one page. If you just remove that and use `\captionof{table}{My caption}` from `caption` package, I think you can do your job.

Comment: Thanks @koleygr! But how can I ensure that the numbering reflects that this is still one Table? (So in the caption it is now saying Table 1: ... and Table2:...?

Comment: Are you aware that you're stretching typographic conventions to the breaking point (and maybe even a bit further) by insisting on calling a collection of `tabular` environments that span several pages a single `table`? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you confident your readers will "get" what you're doing? Or is there a risk that they'll be highly confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

{\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{My caption}
    \captionof{subtable}{Panel A: Some stuff}
    \begin{tabular}{lcr}
        First name & Last name  & Product \\
        Bubba & Gump & Shrimp \\
        Steve & Jobs & Happiness
    \end{tabular}
    \pagebreak

    \captionof{subtable}{Panel B: Other stuff}

    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        School & State \\
        Harvard & MA \\
        Yale & CT \\
        Brown & RI
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: may be the command `\captionsetup[subtable]{labelsep=space,labelformat = parens}' will be usefull for you